# parse error mysql 2 variables

Tags: php, mysql

my code is this

```
$newentry = "
    UPDATE url 
    FROM auction_media 
    JOIN auctions ON auction_media.auction_id = auctions.auction_id                                            
    SET media_url = '$row2['url']/$match[0]' 
    WHERE media_type =  '3'";
```

the error i am getting is

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Answer (score 1):

```
$newentry = "UPDATE `url` FROM `auction_media` JOIN `auctions` ON `auction_media.auction_id` = `auctions.auction_id` SET `media_url` = '".$row2['url']."/".$match[0]."' WHERE `media_type` =  '3'";
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet seems to be wrong:

```
SET media_url = '$row2['url']/$match[0]'
```

Correction is as follows:

```
SET media_url = '" . $row2['url'] . "/" . $match[0] . "'
```

Try this instead:

```
 $newentry = "UPDATE url FROM auction_media JOIN auctions ON auction_media.auction_id = auctions.auction_id SET media_url = '" . $row2['url'] . "/" . $match[0] . "' WHERE media_type =  '3'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that query will actually work:

```
$newentry = "UPDATE url
    FROM auction_media
    JOIN auctions
        ON auction_media.auction_id = auctions.auction_id
    SET media_url = '" . $row2['url'] . '/' . $match[0] . "'
    WHERE media_type =  '3'";
```